# Send-MailMessage change how From email address is displayed in Outlook

Tags: powershell, outlook

When sending an email using PowerShell's `Send-MailMessage -From 'Some person <some.Person@company.com>` Outlook will display the sender in the format of `Some Person <some.person@company.com>` yet when Outlook is used to send the email, the sender is displayed simply as `Some Person`

Is there any way to get the `Send-MailMessage` cmdlet to format the mail message so Outlook will only display the Name and not the Name + Email address?

Searching around on this topic returns plenty of "How to use Send-MailMessage" or answers using `.net` but doesn't really address this question directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `MailAddress` class has a `DisplayName` property you can use to override this.

Unfortunately, `Send-MailMessage` only accepts a string as argument to the `-From` parameter

Try using the [`SmtpClient` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient(v=vs.110).aspx) manually, then overriding the display name of the from address with [this `MailAddress` constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1s17zfkf(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
# Create message, add From mailaddress with custom display name
$Message = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
$Message.From = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailAddress 'some.Person@company.com','Some Person'
$Message.To.Add('recipient@company.com')
$Message.Subject = 'Exciting email!'
$Message.Body = @'
Hi Recipient

Check my cool display name in Outlook!

Regards
Some Person
'@

# Send using SmtpClient
$SmtpClient = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient 'mailserver.fqdn'
$SmtpClient.Send($Message)
```

Comment: Just tested and sadly Outlook refuses to cooperate. The display name of the email still displays as `Some Person <Some.Person@company.com>`

Comment: Now `.net` is being stubborn also, as `'DisplayName' is a ReadOnly property.`

Comment: @user4317867 Yeah you can only set it via the constructor. So, `DisplayName` property shows as `Some person` in powershell before sending, but Outlook still shows `Some Person <Some.Person@company.com>`?

Comment: Correct, what is even more annoying is the new mail popup notification correctly shows the DisplayName only but the mail item includes the full email address.